# Reverse a String and store it in the same variable in Java using String class methods

Tags: java, string, reverse

Suppose there is a string variable `str = "A man is no one!"`, then i need the reverse of this string to be stored in same str  variable as `"!eno on si nam A"`, without using any other object or variable. Could someone please provide the most optimized way to do this?

I already used below piece of code:

```
public static String reverseRecursively(String str) {
        //base case to handle one char string and empty string
        if (str.length() < 2) {
            return str;
        }
        return reverseRecursively(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
```

Any other way of doing this?

Please note that I only want it using `String class methods`.

Comment: Could you provide your not optimized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString()
```

While this does create a new StringBuilder instance, it doesn't store it in a variable, and it would be very tricky (if possible) to reverse the string without ANY new objects whatsoever.

**Edit**

Since you don't want to use anything but `String` methods, here's a simple way to do it with a loop instead, but again it still creates new objects.

```
char[] chars = new char[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    chars[str.length() - i - 1] = str.charAt(i);
}
String newStr = new String(chars);
```

Comment: I do not want to use StringBuilder. I want to reverse using only String class methods.

Comment: @ShashankShekher I've updated my answer.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: @ShashankShekher What's wrong with the one I just made? What are the requirements?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Just want to know if there's any other approach.

Comment: @ShashankShekher there's definitely other approaches but these are the simplest.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the solution!